# ¿como obtener ciudades de un pais concreto?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Buenas.

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para Colombia y necesito las ciudades de ese país y querría saber si alguien conoce alguna extension para Django 1.11 y python 3.5 para obtener las ciudades de un país en concreto. Mi problema es que posiblemente se amplie a otros paises y por eso no puedo introducirlo a mano en un modelo.

Ahora mismo estoy usando un paquete llamado django-cities-light pero en la documentación pone para python 3.3 y da bastantes errores a la hora de exportar las ciudades.

Gracias.

Comment: Usa algun api gratuito para ello,como por ejemplo [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html)

Comment: es la que utiliza es paquete que estoy usando ahora mismo pero al guardar los campos según dice el paquete me da errores. el paquete es este: http://django-cities-light.readthedocs.io/en/stable-3.x.x/

Comment: Has probado con la API de Google?